# how to run regression tests with jenkins

Tags: testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests, regression-testing

Is it possible to run regression tests with Jenkins? (I am not talking about Unit Tests).

Regression tests in my company are some VB scripts (recorded user action in a txt file and then compared to an existing file).
We usually automatically run these using a job and an in-house app.

Is it possible to make Jenkins run these when a build is triggered?

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, y can. You can use this: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin

Comment: In doubt, Jenkins just executes commands.

Answer (score 0):

As [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server, Jenkins is built to

> run regression tests

It is [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extend+Jenkins) based, so you will find it can do pretty much anything you will ever need. It is really a matter of project specific setup. Also, supports different OS for the [Nodes](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781784390891/2/ch02lvl1sec15/understanding-the-master-and-slave-architecture)

[image]

As to desktop apps, when it comes to `SendKeys` and other interactive methods (I assume the process you run is GUI application), you need to run Jenkins slave  agent able to deal with active desktop session, e.g. [jnlp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html) or as (my) workaround - setup keep-alive job every 3 mins.